# HtmlAgilityPack - How do I add data to an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, html-agility-pack

I am trying to add data to an array but everytime I try to add new data, the old data gets deleted. I have 20 pages and the array does not add all the 20 pages but only 1. The rest just gets deleted.

```
HtmlNode[] array = null;

for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
   var doc1 = web.Load(loopingpage);
   array = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class, '-row-cp')]").ToArray();
}
```

The data does not get added to the array. It only displays the current data.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the array in each iteration in the `for` loop in this line.

```
array = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class, '-row-cp')]").ToArray();
```

You could of course add nodes to a predefined array, but arrays are fixed in size, so you would need to know beforehand how many nodes there are to allocate an appropriate size. Instead, you can use a [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1), which is not fixed-size and more suitable for your scenario.

```
// Create a new list of nodes
var nodes = new List<HtmlNode>();

for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
   var doc1 = web.Load(loopingpage);
   var doc1Nodes = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class, '-row-cp')]");

   // Add all selected nodes from doc1 to the list
   nodes.AddRange(doc1Nodes);
}

// Convert it to an array later if needed
var nodesArray = nodes.ToArray();
```